# Implementing logistic regression with L2 regularization in Matlab

Tags: matlab, regression

Matlab has built in logistic regression using mnrfit, however I need to implement a logistic regression with L2 regularization.  I'm completely at a loss at how to proceed. I've found some good papers and website references with a bunch of equations, but not sure how to implement the gradient descent algorithm needed for the optimization.

Is there an easily available sample code in Matlab for this.  I've found some libraries and packages, but they are all part of larger packages, and call so many convoluted functions, one can get lost just going through the trace.

Comment: You're probably better off using some pre-fab optimizer than implementing your own. LBFGS and conjugate gradient are the most widely used algorithms to exactly optimize LR models, not vanilla gradient descent. See e.g. [this toolbox](http://www.di.ens.fr/~mschmidt/Software/minFunc.html).

Comment: If you tag your question correctly (i.e. with the matlab tag) you make it easier for others to find this question and improve your chances for an answer.

Comment: This question may actually get better answers on the statistics stack exchange.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an annotated piece of code for plain gradient descent for logistic regression. To introduce regularisation, you will want to update the cost and gradient equations. In this code, theta are the parameters, X are the class predictors, y are the class-labels and alpha is the learning rate

I hope this helps :)

```
function [theta,J_store] = logistic_gradientDescent(theta, X, y,alpha,numIterations)

% Initialize some useful values
m = length(y); % number of training examples
n = size(X,2); %number of features

J_store = 0;
%J_store = zeros(numIterations,1);


for iter=1:numIterations

    %predicts the class labels using the current weights (theta)
    Z = X*theta;
    h = sigmoid(Z);

    %This is the normal cost function equation
    J = (1/m).*sum(-y.*log(h) - (1-y).*log(1-h));


    %J_store(iter) = J;



    %This is the equation to obtain the given the current weights, without regularisation
    grad = [(1/m) .* sum(repmat((h - y),1,n).*X)]';


    theta = theta - alpha.*grad;


end

end
```